# Although Lorenz system is a deterministic system, can it shows locally stochastic behavior?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

The [Lorenz system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) is a system of ordinary differential equations
$$\begin{aligned}{\frac {\mathrm {d} x}{\mathrm {d} t}}&=\sigma (y-x),\\{\frac {\mathrm {d} y}{\mathrm {d} t}}&=x(\rho -z)-y,\\{\frac {\mathrm {d} z}{\mathrm {d} t}}&=xy-\beta z.\end{aligned}$$
It is notable for having chaotic solutions for certain parameter values and initial conditions. My question is, although it is a deterministic system (because consists of three deterministic ODE), can it shows locally stochastic behavior?

Many tools have been introduced to distinguish between deterministic and stochastic behavior. For example, according to [RQA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_quantification_analysis) (recurrence quantification analysis) there exists a measure (DET) which is called *determinism* and is related with the predictability of the dynamical system. If DET$=1$ (or $=0$) the system is purely deterministic (or stochastic).

Although Lorenz system shows DET near to 1, can it shows locally stochastic behavior?

Comment: You first need to define "local stochastic behavior". The link that you provide describes only some elementary computations, we cannot go far discussing it. Or in other words, if it would be so simple, quite frankly it would make no sense to discuss stochastic behavior.